# Visual Studio AWS toolkit with multifactor authentication?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, google-authenticator, multi-factor-authentication

I have mutifactor authentication setup for web console logins (using google authenticator).

But I can still open VS with the AWS toolkit, it automatically pulls my creds, and I have access to all my AWS services. It also doesn't seem to time out.

I want VS to prompt me for a google authenticator code before it can connect to AWS.

Is this possible?

I'd hate to have MFA for web console logins totally subverted by VS (which may become the tool of choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IAM users, MFA only affects console login. It does not affect the IAM access keys used for that user.

Since Visual Studio uses access keys, it will not prompt you for the MFA device code.

Comment: Is there any kind of workaround to get this functionality with access keys? Is there an external service or something I could have validating the access keys and doing multifactor auth if AWS doesn't support this natively?

Comment: None that I am aware of.